# What is the electronic element shown in the picture of a schematic?

Tags: amplifier, pcb-design, power-amplifier

[image]

And of course, what is it used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.2 Amp circuit breaker.  A little more of the schematic would be useful to give some context.

Comment: It's part of a power amplifier; at the output of the amplifier IC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to find that it's a thermal switch- a type of overcurrent protection device.